# TFS not auto logging-in and no context menu

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs, contextmenu

I've just re-installed my entire system (Win7 and VS2008 in particular) and then re-installed Team Foundation Server.

My problem is that when I open Visual Studio, I don't automatically get logged in to TFS like I used to.

And then, once I have logged in, if I right-click on my solution, projects, etc., I don't have any TFS options such as "Get Latest Version".

I've re-installed TFS and restarted the PC, but still the same.

Does anyone have any ideas what I need to do to fully configure TFS so that I'm automatically logged in and the TFS context menu items appear?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the Team Explorer as well as Visual Studio 2008 SP1 installed to have all team explorer options in Visual Studio.

To get automatically logged in you can use the Windows Credential manager (Control Panel > Credential Manager) and add a "Generic Credential" for your TFS server.

Comment: By now I've installed Visual Studio 2008 sp1, Team Foundation Client, Visual Studio 2008 Team Explorer, and I've created a generic credential.
No change.
I still have to manually sign into TFS, then when I open a solution I still don't have the context menu items that go with TFS.
Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you bind your solution to Source Control (File -> Source Control -> Change Source Control)?

Comment: Manually sign in: Make the Generic Credential is set up correctly (Domain/username, correct web address etc.), you can test that the credential is working with Internet Explorer when going to the same URL and if no login window appears and you are logged in automatically it works. That you still don't have a context menu MUST be a installation issue. I don't remember the correct order, but I think you had to install SP1 after installing everything, otherwise some problems might arise.

Comment: It appears that I've solved half of the problem: Once I've signed into TFS I get a right-click option on my solution, labelled "Go online". This then brings up a report of items which have changed since I last communicated with TFS, and once all these items have been resolved, the source control padlocks appear next to each item in Solution Explorer, and the expected context menu options are there (Get Latest, Get Specific version etc.)
I'm still having to sign into TFS when Visual Studio boots up though. However, maybe if I now re-apply sp1 after everything else it might make a difference.